# How do I center multiple "relative" divs with stacked images?

Tags: css, html

I want a set of divs stacked sideways, like so:

```
D0
---------------------------------------
|     ------ ------ ------ ------     |
|     |    | |    | |    | |    |     |
|     | D1 | | D2 | | D3 | | D4 |     |
|     |    | |    | |    | |    |     |
|     ------ ------ ------ ------     |
---------------------------------------
```

Centered within D1. I can do this by setting D0 to `text-align:center`. (I cannot use margin:auto, since I don't know the width of D1 - D4 combined).

However, D1 through D4 contain a bunch of images I want to overlay. I can do this by setting `position: relative` for D1, and `position:absolute` for the img tags.

The issue is that this causes D1-D4 to seem like they have no content, and they lose their ability to center with text-align:center! Is there some other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Just to confirm - you don't know / can't set the width of any of the D1-4 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `display : inline-block` for `d1, d2 d3` and `d4` (along with a `vertical-align`) and use `text-align: center` on the parent

Relative positioning is not necessary for those elements

Comment: Without positioning, how do I super-impose the images?

Comment: it's not necessary for central alignment but is fine for image effect

Comment: @Vanwaril - `display:inline-block` makes them an inline element, so then `text-align:center` can center it.

Comment: @Derek, why not `display:inline`?

Comment: Because then it will loose the properties of `block`. eg: no `transform` for `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think y may now as like this

***Css***

```
.d0{
    width:70%;
    background:green;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.d0 div{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 0;
}

 .d1{
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
}

 .d2{
    background:pink;
}


 .d3{
    background:darkred;
}


 .d4{
    background:lightblue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="d0">

    <div class="d1">D1</div>
    <div class="d2">D2</div>
    <div class="d3">D3</div>
    <div class="d4">D4</div>

</div>
​
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/qCtwp/

### --------------------------------------------------

or if you used table than http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/qCtwp/1/

Answer (score 0):

May you are using `flot:left` property to divs, remove that and u can use `display:inline` for divs then it will be in center of D0

Comment: If I have D1-D4 `float: left; display: inline`, they drift to the far left of D0, not center.

Comment: @Vanwaril, created a fixed size `<div>` (d0), then use `margin: 0px auto` to center.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id=d0 style="">
    <center><div id="dgroup" style="padding-top:10%;">
        <div id=d1 style="float:left;width=100px;height:180px">
              this is d1
        </div>

        <div id=d2 style="float:left;width=100px;height:180px">
              this is d2
        </div>

        <div id=d3 style="float:left;width=100px;height:180px">
              this is d3
        </div>

    </div></center>
</div>
```

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated in HTML 4.01 and not supported *at all* in HTML5. Do not use it!

Comment: @ChristianVarga : hey you have do not mentioned "need code for HTML5". dude

Comment: HTML5 is the current standard, so if you're assuming anything, you should assume HTML5. Regardless, best practices and semantics shouldn't be ignored just because they "weren't mentioned".